# Select and Iterate over the Properties

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to read a content from the list of properties with one of the property being an object. What do I need to use to read a string and object properties?

Here is the output of `Get-Member` of the list

```
PS> $r | Get-Member

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method     type GetType()
ToString          Method     string ToString()
ActivityName      Property   string ActivityName {get;}
DurationInMs      Property   System.Nullable[int] DurationInMs {get;}
Error             Property   System.Object Error {get;}
Input             Property   System.Object Input {get;}
Output            Property   System.Object Output {get;}
Status            Property   string Status {get;}


PS> $r.Output | Get-Member

...
Name            Property       string Name {get;}
Next            Property       Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken Next {get;}
Path            Property       string Path {get;}
Previous        Property       Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken Previous {get;}
Root            Property       Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken Root {get;}
...
```

(It's a long list, hiding unnecessary details)

I am trying to select ActivityName, DurationInMs and Values of Output in Table format. The Root Property in Output object has values for dataRead, dataWritten properties.

This is what I tried:

```
$r | Select ActivityName,DurationInMs
```

Output:

```
ActivityName     DurationInMs
------------     ------------
SetDay                     78
Set TS                     15
LKUP_FileControl        12206
CopyPaths               38585
```

I also tried this:

```
$r.Output | select @{name="dataRead"; expression={$_.Root.dataRead.Value}},@{name="dataWritten"; expression={$_.Root.dataWritten.Value}}
```

Output:

```
dataRead     dataWritten
--------     -----------


520114512    520114512
520114512    520114512
520114512    520114512
0            0
0            0
0            0
3199091788   3199091788
3199091788   3199091788
3199091788   3199091788
```

(Note: This is resulting in duplicates as the Root property has other nested properties inside)

I expect the output to be in table format, like:

```
ActivityName     DurationInMs    dataRead      dataWritten
------------     ------------    ---------    ------------
SetDay                     78
Set TS                     15    520114512       520114512
LKUP_FileControl        12206            0               0
CopyPaths               38585   3199091788      3199091788
```

How can I do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine your two code snippets to get the desired result:

```
$r | Select-Object ActivityName, DurationInMs,
    @{n='dataRead';e={$_.Output.Root.dataRead.Value}},
    @{n='dataWritten';e={$_.Output.Root.dataWritten.Value}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar. That works like a charm. Is there a way I can bring this as part of the above output? Please note, this is present only in the 2nd array. `**$r[2].Output.value | Select-Object {$_.SRC_PATH.Value} **

-----------------
/computed
/published/restricted_product
/published/eim/managed/entpr_customer
/published/internal
/published/restricted_finance
/published/restricted_distribution
/published/eim/managed/entpr_product
` These are paths from where the data is read but unfortunately it is not at the same level as dataRead and dataWritten properties.

Comment: Figured this out by myself. Thanks @Ansgar once again.